# External blocking scripts force the browser to wait, before the page can be rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, blocking, google-contacts-api

See: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

They are saying:

> External blocking scripts force the browser to wait for the JavaScript to be fetched, which may add one or more network roundtrips before the page can be rendered.

Why Google is saying something like that? It's so confusing for people. Actually they are saying:

> External blocking scripts force the browser to wait before the page can be rendered.

They are NOT saying:

> External blocking scripts force the browser to wait before A (SPECIFIC) PART OF the page can be rendered.

Let's take this example:

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Line 1<br />

        <script>
            alert('I could also put here for example some more html.');
        </script>

        Line 2<br />

        <script src="script.js"></script>

        Now the HTML parser is almost done!<br />
    </body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT.JS

```
// Synchronous delay of 30 seconds
var timeWhile = new Date().getTime(); 
while( new Date().getTime() - timeWhile < 30000 );
```

This is the test: https://external-blocking-scripts-2.glitch.me/

The result is that a browser is showing (rendering) already content, before the "external blocking script" is fetched.

So why Google is saying it like that? In my opinion "a page" is something completely different than "a part of the page". People would really make wrong decisions in terms of "page speed" if they are seeing it like that. And i'm posting this, because in the past i was also one of them. And i'm still seeing the confusion around me.